# Difference between Find and FindAsync in regard of lazyness

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I found something interesting, a piece of code that doesn't work that way I figured and I hope someone could clarify things for me.

I have this two lines:

```
    var books = await collection.FindAsync(book => book.OwnerId == ownerId);
    return books.ToEnumerable();
```

1. I added a breakpoint on the second line and launch the application.
2. After the brakpoint hits I remove all entries from the DB and continue exectuing the application.
3. To my suprise entries were return, meaning that FindAsync execute a query on invoketion i.e. not lazy

I wanted to make sure I'm not crazy and that the Find method is lazy unlike it's async sibling. I changed the code to use Find instead of FindAsync and restarted the process:

```
    var books = collection.Find(book => book.OwnerId == ownerId);
    return books.ToEnumerable();
```

This time I got nothing back(as expected since Find is lazy and shouldn't execute the query)

Somebody knows to explain this? Is FindAsync really not lazy? Is that intentional? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RoarS.,
Actually no. I read that post before but it didn't answer my question. On the contrary. It's said that both FindAsync and Find are asynchrnous but Find is not asynchrnous and FindAsync is not lazy. What I'm missing is a lazy command that I can use the "await" keyword with. That wahy I get the most of two wrolds-  I can let the compiler know it can use the thread while querying on one hand, but run the query only when needed on thet other hand.

Comment: I see that you're getting help on this one, and it seems like you've done some research in advance, hope things are getting solved. BR

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is pretty clear here:

- [`FindAsync`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindAsync__1.htm):

> Finds the documents matching the filter.

- [`FindSync`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindSync__1.htm):

> Finds the documents matching the filter.

- [`Find`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1.htm):

> Begins a fluent find interface.

The issue here is that `Find` and `FindAsync` aren't sync and async verisons of the same method; `FindAsync` and `FindSync` are.

Comment: Thanks, prettry strange though... If I want the reading operation to be lazy but to be able to use await what method should I use?

Comment: @RiskX use `Find`. I often use `await collection.Find(stuff).ToListAsync()` for example. You can decouple the find from the `await` and `.ToListAsync();` part.

Comment: @Lama Yes, I need to decoulpe the Find from ToListAsync to ensure lazy querying. The problem is ToListAsync is not an extension method of IEnumerable and I don't want any Mongo Driver implementations (like IFindFluent) outside of my DAL classes.